# Refactor Windows Forms to MVP

Tags: winforms, compact-framework, mvp, opennetcf.ioc

The project I am working on is a mobile .NET CF based application. I have to implement the  MVP pattern in it. I am now using OpenNETCF.IoC library and Services in it.

I have to refactor Windows Forms code to SmartParts.

I have a problem in implementing navigation scenario:

```
// Show Main menu    
bodyWorkspace.Show(mainMenuView);

// Show First view based on user choice    
bodyWorkspace.Show(firstView);

// In first view are some value(s) entered and these values should be passed to the second view    
bodyWorkspace.Show(secondView); // How?
```

In Windows Forms logic this is implemented with variables:

```
var secondForm = new SecondForm();
secondForm.MyFormParameter = myFormParameter;
```

How can I reimplement this logic in MVP terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It greatly depends on your architecture, but this would be my suggestion:

First, ViewB does *not* need information in ViewA.  It needs information either in the Model or a Presenter.  ViewA and ViewB should get their info from the same place.

This could be done, as an example, by a service.  This could look like this:

```
class ParameterService
{
    public int MyParameter { get; set; }
}

class ViewA
{
    void Foo()
    {
        // could also be done via injection - this is just a simple example
        var svc = RootWorkItem.Services.Get<ParameterService>();
        svc.MyParameter = 42;
    }
}

class ViewB
{
    void Bar()
    {
        // could also be done via injection - this is just a simple example
        var svc = RootWorkItem.Services.Get<ParameterService>();
        theParameter = svc.MyParameter;
    }
}
```

Event Aggregation, also supported in [the IoC framework you're using](http://ioc.codeplex.com), could also work, where ViewA publishes an event that ViewB subscribes to. [An example of this can be found here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2009/10/30/project-resistance-event-aggregation-with-opennetcf-ioc/), but generally speaking you'll use the `EventPublication` and `EventSubscription` attributes (the former on an event in ViewA, the latter on a method in ViewB).